# Do both bash and sh wait for a command to terminate before executing the next one?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, execution

Do both `bash` and `sh` wait for a command to terminate before executing the next one?

I have run some scripts when I expected commands to execute one after the other (ie commands on different lines) but it didn't seem to work that way. I can't recollect the exact scripts offhand but I separated the commands with the `&&` symbol.

If you cut and paste lines from a script of a how to into a terminal is it guaranteed that earlier lines will finish before the following lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have pipes `|` or background jobs `&`, then the evaluation may be non-sequential, otherwise it does evaluate things one after the other.

However, if the output is in different streams, they could be coming to the console out of order. For instance, if you print to both STDOUT and STDERR, the lines within each streams will be in order, but they might be interleaved in a way that does not reflect the order printing was done in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. As long as the commands are executed in the foreground. i.e. no "&" character at the end of the command line.

May be a space crept in inside your "&&"

Answer (score 2):

Yes it executes sequentially... But if you run a job in the backgroud using & then it may not work as you expected. Because those jobs will run in the background.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, yes.  A command will execute, its return value will become available when the command finishes and then the next command will run.

The shell can be directed to start a background job by adding a `&` to the job such as:

```
somecommand &
anothercommand
```

In this case, `somecommand` will execute in the background and `anothercommand` may be started (and may also finish) before `somecommand` has completed.